# Попадает ли точка в заштрихованную область?

Tags: c++

Попадает ли точка с заданными координатами в заштрихованную область?

[image]

Comment: @Rimp, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Во-первых, не факт, что это девушка. Считать, что какие-то профессии только для женщин, а какие-то для мужчин - это моветон. Вы знаете, что бывают женщины-космонавты? Почему бы не быть мужчине-акушеру?

Во-вторых, мне бы очень интересно было узнать, зачем акушерам C++.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что работа за автора

Answer (score 2):

Определить, с какой стороны от прямой находится точка, можно через простое неравенство.

[image]

У вас четыре прямые на координатной плоскости:

```
y = -x+5
y = -x+11
y = x+3
y = x-3
```

Проставив нужные знаки неравенства, вы отсечете искомую вами фигуру.

```
(y > -x+5) and (y < -x+11) and (y < x+3) and (y > x-3)
```

[image]

Итоговое решение на С++ записывается в пару строк.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x, y;
    cin >> x >> y;

    if((y > -x+5) && (y < -x+11) && (y < x+3) && (y > x-3)) cout << "Попадает";
        else cout << "Не попадает";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Мне одному непонятно, зачем тут C++11? А на C++03 или, страшно сказать, голом C эта задача уже считается нерешаемой? Я считаю, что преподавание информатики на C++ (заметьте - не преподавание самого C++) - это преступление хуже педофилии. Педофил, по крайней мере, не всем своим ученикам жизнь ломает. Те, кто считает, что информатику надо преподавать на C++ - опасные сумасшедшие. Даже к преподавателям, до сих пор втуляющим детям Turbo Pascal и QBASIC, я отношусь лучше. Они просто безобидные деревенские дурачки.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int higher(a, b, x, y)
{
    return y > a * x + b;
}

int main(void)
{
    int x, y;
    while (scanf("%d %d", &x, &y) == 2)
    {
        int inside = higher(-1, 5, x, y) &&
                     higher(1, -3, x, y) &&
                     !higher(1, 3, x, y) &&
                     !higher(-1, 11, x, y);
        printf("%s\n", inside ? "Yes!" : "No.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Метку исправил C++11 на C++.

Answer (score 0):

Осторожно, говнокод!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x=2,y=4;
    if (x<1 || x>7 || y<0)
    cout << "Нет\n";
    x-=4;y-=4; 
    if (x>0) 
    x-=(3+x);
    if (y<(3+x) && y>(-3-x))
    cout << "Да\n";
    else
    cout << "Нет\n";

    return 0;
}
```